# Dynamically set decimal place of number in Python

Tags: python, decimal

Let's say i have following variables:

```py
something = 123456789  
decimal = 5
```

I want to set the decimal place of `something` based on the value of `decimal` so that for the above example i get:

```py
something = 1234.56789
```

Now let's say `decimal = 15` then i need to get:

```py
something = 0.000000123456789
```

How to do this in the most pythonic way?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you actually want decimals or just floats? E.g. should ``something, decimal = 11, 1`` be *exactly* ``1.1`` or just roughly?

Comment: No rounding. Needs to be exact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply by dividing with 10 to the power of decimal.

```
something = 123456789
decimal = 15
print(something / 10 ** decimal)
```